# How to pytest a Flask Endpoint

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-restful

I'm getting started with Flask and Pytest in order to implemente a rest service with unit test, but i'm having some troouble.

I'll like to make a simple test for my simple endpoint but i keep getting a `Working outside of application context.` error when running the test.

This is the end point:

```
from flask import jsonify, request, Blueprint
STATUS_API = Blueprint('status_api', __name__)

def get_blueprint():
    """Return the blueprint for the main app module"""
    return STATUS_API


@STATUS_API.route('/status', methods=['GET'])
def get_status():
    return jsonify({
        'status' : 'alive'
    })
```

And this is how I'm trying to test it (i know it should fail the test):

```
import pytest

from routes import status_api

def test_get_status():
    assert status_api.get_status() == ''
```

I'm guessing I just cant try the method with out building the whole app. But if that's the case i dont really know how to aproach this problem

Answer (score 6):

The [Flask documentation on testing](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/) is pretty good.

Instead of importing the view functions, you should create a so called `test client`, e.g. as a pytest fixture.

For my last Flask app this looked like:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app = create_app()
    app.config['TESTING'] = True

    with app.app_context():
        with app.test_client() as client:
            yield client
```

(`create_app` is my app factory)

Then you can easily create tests as follows:

```
def test_status(client):
    rv = client.get('/stats')
    assert ...
```

As mentioned at the beginning, the [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/) is really good.

Comment: Here's the documentation which I found useful - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/testing/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying an API client/development tool? [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) and [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) are popular ones. Using one may be able to resolve this for you.